# Google Sheets JSON endpoint change

Tags: angular, google-sheets

My angular web app reads data from a google sheet, however about a week ago i noticed that it was no longer able to read json from the endpoint I had been using:

`https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/${sheetid}/${sheetno}/public/values?alt=json`

I haven't been able to find anything in Google's api or changelogs indicating they changed something, but I have found some unanswered posts in subreddits of other people with the same issue.

Was there a change?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the new endpoint (V4)

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
```

with id of the spreadsheet and gid of the sheet
https://codepen.io/mikesteelson/pen/wvevppe